# Python regexp conundrum

Tags: python, sql, regex

I am trying to break a huge SQL file into little sql file and I am using python to achieve this, but the code that I'm using doesn't match and from what I've seen on google it should.

Here is the code:

```
    import sys, re
    p = [0]
    f = open('/root/testsql/data.sql', 'r')
    tables =["tabel1", "table2"]
    contor = 0;
    con = 0;

    for line in f:
        for table in tables:
            stri = "root/testsql/" + str(con)
            con = con + 1
            stri2 = ".*" + table + ".*"
            if re.match(stri2,line):
                    print table
                    f2 = open(stri,"w")
                    f2.write(line)
                    f2.close()
```

If anybody has an idea why re.match doesn't work, it would be much appreciated.

The sql file is very long (73595 lines)and contains lines like:

```
insert into table ...
insert into table
```

Comment: What is the output when you write f2? Edit: or is that not happening at all?

Comment: I have no output, that is the problem. I have the print table in that if just to verify that i enter the if but there is no output, so it doesn't enter the loop

Comment: Copying the text you show for your lines and tables and then doing an `re.match` did lead to matchs.  Are you sure the text you show is what you're getting from the file?

Comment: I hope it's not the real account data that you have posted.

Comment: Serves me right for working over time, I can't even think straight

Comment: @GreenMatt yes i'm pretty sure. I have tried a match with the exact data that i'm using in the script and it worked. I have selected a table name and checked if it could match in a line in where it appeared and it did.

Comment: You are aware that the data you posted is still visible in the edits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only looking for verbatim strings. In that case, regex is overkill. Instead, use `in`:

```
for line in f:
    for table in tables:
        # snip...
        if table in line:
            # ...
```

Comment: I think the matching was not the problem. I used your suggestion, but still no result. No files were created and nothing was shown to the console output. The thing is there are 73595 lines and some of them are very long and maybe that is why it doesn't work.

Comment: I tested from the python console and it worked with your suggestion, but still from the script it doesn't work.

Comment: @primero: You're right, my approach wouldn't have changed the results. But the length of the lines is certainly not the problem. I think you should insert some more `print` statements and check whether the program flow really is as expected. And maybe check your SQL file in an editor and do some searches there to make sure.

Comment: @primero: Hmm, grasping at straws here. What character encoding does your SQL file use? Not UTF-16 by any chance? What do you get when you insert a `print line` after `for line in f:`?

Comment: Well I get the INSERT statements one by one separated by a new line

Comment: @TimPietzcker it's UTF-16 encoded, but I'm not sure how this counts in my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
stri2 = ".*" + table + ".*"
```

should be:

```
stri2 = ".*?" + table + ".*"
```

The .* is *greedy* and will match the whole line.

Comment: it should be faster this way, but `.*` should backtrack in the first place

Comment: Still not entering the if statement. I tried on the python console my match statement and it seemed to work, but i can't seem to enter the in the if from my script.

Comment: And as you can see from the code in the if statement i create some files. None of them get created. I'm new to python an I don't know how to debug this.

Comment: @primero - the info you provided in comments belongs to the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `re.search` instead of `re.match` instead of wrapping the regex in `.*`.

The reason why you see no matches is that the the inputs end with a newline, and the dot metacharacter does not match newlines.

Comment: My first draft was with re.search, and i used re.compile to create my pattern but i don't know how to test in the if statement.

Comment: f2 is not a file, but a lot of files, 1 in each cycle, so `w` is ok in this case

Comment: But now that i think of it it might be the same like in my example

Comment: Ad 1: True, but the regex should still have matched. Ad 2: He's not appending anything. He's writing lots of one-line files. Or trying to.

Comment: @primero - `re.search` is used in exactly the same way as `re.match` except that it will fix your code.  It returns the same kind of a match object.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a raw string instead of a plain string in any regular expression so that you don't end up fooling yourself when a char get interpreted.

r'.*' + table + r'.*'